# Get two numbers in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s='123223423424,1982379879343'
```

I need to get both numbers (without using a `split()`). Here is what I have so far:

```
re.match(r'\d{7,20}',s).group()
```

However, this only gives me the first item.

How would I get the following output?:

```
out = [123223423424, 1982379879343]
```

Note that the regex should pull out all numbers of between 7 and 20 digits and put them into a list.

Comment: use `findall`, not `match`.

Comment: 'I need to get both numbers (without using a split()). Here is what I have so far:' means that you ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.findall` to return a list of matches from your string. For example:

```
>>> out = re.findall(r'\d{7,20}', '123223423424,1982379879343')
>>> out
['123223423424', '1982379879343']
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.